# List of Users and Role using Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I’m trying to produce a view to show a list of users and their role using the built in membership provider.

My model and controller are picking up the users and roles but I’m having trouble displaying them in my view.

**Model**

```
public class AdminViewModel
    {
        public MembershipUserCollection Users { get; set; }
        public string[] Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Admin()
{
      AdminViewModel viewModel = new AdminViewModel
      {
            Users = MembershipService.GetAllUsers(),
        Roles = RoleService.GetRoles()
      };

      return View(viewModel);
}
```

**View**

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Account.Models.AdminViewModel>>"

<table>

<tr>
    <td>UserName</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>IsOnline</td>
    <td>CreationDate</td>
    <td>LastLoginDate</td>
    <td>LastActivityDate</td>
</tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

<tr>
    <td><%=item.UserName %></td>
    <td><%=item.Email %></td>
    <td><%=item.IsOnline %></td>
    <td><%=item.CreationDate %></td>
    <td><%=item.LastLoginDate %></td>
    <td><%=item.LastActivityDate %></td>
    <td><%=item.ROLE %></td>
</tr>

<% }%>

</table>
```

Comment: ...and what kind of trouble are you having exactly?

Comment: On my view I'm getting error... Account.Models.AdminViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'UserName' and no extension method 'UserName' accepting a first argument of type 'Account.Models.AdminViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

Like Andrew said, you need to make your View inherit from `AdminViewModel`, not `IEnumerable<AdminViewModel>`. Once that is corrected you'll need to iterate over `Model.Users`, instead of `Model` in your `foreach`. `Model.Users` will contain the `MembershipUser` objects with the Username property.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Users) { %>

<tr>
    <td><%=item.UserName %></td>
    <td><%=item.Email %></td>
    <td><%=item.IsOnline %></td>
    <td><%=item.CreationDate %></td>
    <td><%=item.LastLoginDate %></td>
    <td><%=item.LastActivityDate %></td>
    <td><%=item.ROLE %></td>
</tr>

<% }%>
```

Comment: I've removed the IEnumerable and added Model.Users but I'm now getting the error... 'object' does not contain a definition for 'UserName' and no extension method 'UserName' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of trouble it is? 
Please, make sure under debugger that lists you put into model are populated (non-empty).

By the way:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
```

looks like you mentioned

```
foreach (var item in Model.Users)
```

Comment: When I use foreach (var item in Model.Users) I'm not picking up the Users model.

Comment: When I debug the site the model in my controller has values for Users and Roles.

Comment: Please, remove IEnumerable<...>  from you model type definition. You pass only one instance of AdminViewModel 

Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Account.Models.AdminViewModel>>