# In ASP.NET MVC 3 with built-in user login using Forms, how can I retrieve a list of currently logged in users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am making an app in C# using MVC 3 and I'm trying to learn about the built-in user stuff that comes for free (in the `Membership` class).

I want to make a page on my site that lists every user who is currently logged in. Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: Check out MvcMembership, its pluggable user admin area for MVC - http://mvcmembership.codeplex.com/

Comment: Sounds complicated to me... I am just looking for a simple solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var onlineUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers()
    .Cast<MembershipUser>().Where(u => u.IsOnline);
```

Make sure you "bump" the users to be online.

Comment: after a few minute the online user isn't  showed as online why ? after relogin is showed for few minuts againt :(

Answer (score -1):

You can learn more on how to retrieve list of users and bind it to a view in this previously asked question on StackOverflow:

[List of Users and Role using Membership Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827957/list-of-users-and-role-using-membership-provider)

Comment: That just gets a list of all users, not the currently logged in ones.